# How to get single variables out of 3 dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, explode

I've got something I think it is a 3 dimensional array:

```
$var = '1,Tony,186|2,Andrea,163|3,Peter,178|4,Sally,172';
```

So there are 2 arrays packed inside the variable. First is separated by | the second one by ,

What I need to do is: separate them and then check for an ID located before the name and give me single variables of the rest.
I tried it like this:

```
<?php
$personid = 3;

$var = '1,Tony,186|2,Andrea,163|3,Peter,178|4,Sally,172';

$array = explode('|',$var);

foreach($array as $values) {
    $arr = explode(",",$values);
    foreach($arr as $value) {
        if($value[0] == $personid) {
        $id = $value[0];
        $name = $value[1];
        $height = $value[2];
        $killloop = 1;
        }
    }
    if($killloop == 1) {
    break;
    }
}

echo 'ID: '.$id.'<br> Name: '.$name.'<br> Height: '.$height;

?>
```

But all i get then is:

```
ID: 3
Name:
Height:
```

Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need loop Into Second Array, You already have defined positions.
Always Use break statement to end a Loop immediately, Its a good practice

```
<?php
$personid = 3;

$var = '1,Tony,186|2,Andrea,163|3,Peter,178|4,Sally,172';

$array = explode('|',$var);

foreach($array as $values) {
    $arr = explode(",",$values);
    if(!empty($arr) && $arr[0] == $personid){
        $id = $arr[0];
        $name = $arr[1];
        $height = $arr[2];
        break;
    }
}

echo 'ID: '.$id.'<br> Name: '.$name.'<br> Height: '.$height;

?>
```

Comment: Hmmm, I am wondering why but my comment has been deleted. THANK YOU SO MUCH! Thinking too complicated sometimes. :)